# How to define empty array in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I know how to make array of string data in swagger like this:

```
"photoUrls" : {
    "type":"array",
    "items":{
         "type":"string"
    }
}
```

It will show output like this:

```
"photoUrls":[
    "string"
]
```

How to make output like this?:

```
"photoUrls":[]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't. The idea is that

```
"photoUrls":[
    "string"
]
```

shows your users that `photoUrls` is an array of strings. Otherwise, they will have no way of knowing which datatype is used by the array.

Comment: They would, in JSON the empty array is [], swagger should be returning am empty array instead of null

Comment: Why should I show my users that my array is an array of strings, if it is not? There are cases, where it is and will always be empty, like in my case. In JS it does not matter to the programmer user, what complex object structure there would be in non-error case, when I'm about to describe the error case. Do I have to define the complete object type and then add a comment that it will always be empty? Using any dummy type to satisfy the requirements and putting [] as "example" is a confusing workaround, but no desirable solution.

Answer (score 24):

You can specify an empty array `[]` as an `example` for your array schema. This will override the default examples values generated by Swagger UI.

```
"photoUrls" : {
    "type":"array",
    "items":{
         "type":"string"
    },
    "example": []
}
```

[Ron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29625520/113116) is more user-friendly for your users. Consider using some real-world `example` values instead:

```
"photoUrls" : {
    "type":"array",
    "items":{
         "type":"string",
         "example": "http://example.com/images/pet.png"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A little late but something I tried showed up quite nicely in the swagger.io UI

my array:

```
conversationStarters: []
```

YAML to make it so the example shows the above:

```
conversationStarters:
   type: array
   items:
     type: string
   maxItems: 0
```

Comment: that works for the example built by the ui, but now the array has to be empty all the time which is not intended